# Update IOT device twin from azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-iot-hub

I need to update multiple device twins i.e. device twins of multiple devices by providing the device id as input. Is there any tool available in the portal that’ll help me provide device ids as input and update the twin with given value?

Comment: There is no such tool available in the portal. You could write a script to do it and upload it to the cloud shell in the portal if that counts. Is there a reason it has to be done from the portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Matthijs in the comment, there is no built-in feature for that in the portal. However, you can use for that needs an Azure CLI in the Azure Portal   for creating an [IoT Hub job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub/job?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-hub-job-create), see my example:

```
az iot hub job create --job-id job10 --job-type scheduleUpdateTwin -n rk2017-iot --twin-patch "{'properties':{'desired': {'temperature': 22.22}}}"  --query-condition "deviceId IN ['Device1', 'Device10']"
```

[image]

[image]